# Cannot see tabs in Cube Designer

Tags: sql-server-2012, cube

There's a data cube in SQL Server 2012 which I'm connecting to, but when I open Analysis Services, and browse the cube, I can't see tabs there like "Calculations", "Cube Structure", etc. Is it just a setting, or is it a permission thing? I do have admin rights on the server.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: What software are you using to open the cube?

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio 2012, and I connect to the cube in Analysis Services

Comment: You're looking for SQL Server Data Tools, or SSDT for short - that's the software you need to be able to edit cubes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AHiggins ! You saved the day :)